# c# how to click link from html code get by OuterHtml

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I need to click this link

```
<li class="SidebarLink"><a title="" class="SidebarLink SidebarLinkChVAT" onclick="FWDC.executeAction(1005, null, 'FLOW');" href="javascript:;">Sprawdź podmiot w VAT</a></li>
```

I get it from webbrowser control like this:

```
string code = webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
```

I try also to found and click this link like this:

```
HtmlElementCollection links=webBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("li class");

foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.InnerText.Equals("Sprawdź podmiot w VAT"))
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

But then this link can't be found.

Is there any possibility to click this link when I save it to string format?

Comment: Would InvokeScript not work better for you? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlElementCollection links=webBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("a"); // li is not a link.i think this wrong

foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if(link.GetAttribute("className") == "SidebarLink SidebarLinkChVAT") //if classname uniq
     {
         //if (link.InnerText.Equals("Sprawdź podmiot w VAT")) 
            link.InvokeMember("Click");
     }
}
```

or

```
HtmlElementCollection lists =webBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("li"); 

foreach (HtmlElement list in lists)
{
    if(list.GetAttribute("className") == "SidebarLink") //or if(list.InnerHtml.Contains("what u search"))
     {
       HtmlElementCollection links=list.GetElementsByTagName("a");
       foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
       {
         if (link.InnerText.Equals("Sprawdź podmiot w VAT")) 
            link.InvokeMember("Click");
       }
     }
}
```